# Android splitting json output in my input fields,

Tags: php, android, json

i have tried this code.During onclick it works fine, but in my output my json values not show up in the output fields,,
but when i replace json code with `childname.setText(result);` i can get the output which shows in the below screenshot
I want to split this values and show it in the respective inputfields.
Suggestion plz,,,,Thanks in advance

[image]

My Javafile

```
public class ChildProfile extends Activity {
    private TextView childname,childid;

    private Button get;
    private EditText username,password;
    private JSONObject jObj;
    private static String user,pass,json,child,id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.child_profile);
        username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_username);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.profile_password);
        childname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_email);
        childid=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_childid);
        get=(Button) findViewById(R.id.profile_button1);
        get.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                valuess();
                if(!user.equals("") & !pass.equals(""))
                {
                new sendPostData().execute(); 
                }
                else if(pass.equals("") & user.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(ChildProfile.this,"Enter Username & Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                       toast.show();
                }
                else if(user.equals("") )
                {
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(ChildProfile.this,"Enter Username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                       toast.show();
                }
                else if(pass.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(ChildProfile.this,"Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                       toast.show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    private class sendPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
            @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {  

     try{ 
                    valuess();
                    String link="http://192.168.1.6:81/arun/value.php";
                    String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") 
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8");
                    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") 
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter
                    (conn.getOutputStream()); 
                    wr.write( data ); 
                    wr.flush(); 
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())); 
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    // Read Server Response
                    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                       sb.append(line);
                       break;
                    }
                   return sb.toString();
                 }catch(Exception e){
                    return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                 }

        }
           @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //View your result here.
              /* if(result.equals("wrong"))
               {
                   Toast toast=Toast.makeText(ChildProfile.this,"Invalid account.Enter correct username and password or Please SignUp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   toast.show(); 
               }
               else
               {
                   Toast toast=Toast.makeText(ChildProfile.this,"Invalid account.Enter correct username and password or Please SignUp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                   toast.show();               
               }
               json=result;
               try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             try {
                child=jObj.getString("ChildPassportName");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                id=jObj.getString("ChildID");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             childid.setText(id);
             Toast toast=Toast.makeText(ChildProfile.this,"Invalid account.Enter correct username and password or Please SignUp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           toast.show();*/
         childname.setText(result);
            }
     }
    public  void valuess()
    {
         user = username.getText().toString(); 
         pass = password.getText().toString();
    }
    }
```

My PHP file

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","arun","sachin11");

$db_select = mysql_select_db('Schoolapp', $con);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ChildPassportName,ChildID FROM SchoolDB where Username='$username' and Password='$password'",$con);
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);

?>
```

php output

```
[{"ChildPassportName":"Arun","ChildID":"0"}]
```

Comment: you need to parse that json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Your getting result as **JSONArray** so you have to parse it.

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

             String id = "";
             String name = "";

             try {
                   JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(result);    
                   JSONObject obj = new_array.getJSONObject(0);
                   id = obj.getString("ChildID"):
                   name = obj.getString("ChildPassportName"):
             }catch (JSONException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
             }

             childid.setText(id);
             childname.setText(name);
        }
```

Comment: It works,,,,I have tried this code but forget to convert to json array
@hariharan ,,,Thank you